# Unexpected Delay calling Soap Service from .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, soap

I am experiencing a delay when calling a .NET 4.7 SOAP service from my x86 .NET Core(6) running on Windows 7 SP1.

I've created a small test program that calls a method on the SOAP service every 1 second and logs how long each call takes. I seems that about every 100 calls/seconds 1 call will take 10+ seconds. Using Wireshark I've deduced that the delay occurs before the call is actually made, as once Wireshark saw the request a return response is made with ~200ms.

If I rebuild my simple app using .NET 4.7 I still receive the delay but its significantly less frequent and long.

Unfortunately due to hardware requirements I cannot upgrade from Windows 7, also changing my main application (not the test) from .NET Core would be quite extensive. I don't see any delay when running x86 on Windows 10+, nor when running x64 on 10+

Does anyone know why I am experiencing this sever delay using .NET 6?

I've attempted to check if the delay is generated by XMLSerialization.dll being rebuilt, but no changes came from that investigation.

```
internal class Program
{
  private static soapClient client = new soapClient(new soapClient.EndpointConfiguration(), "url");
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    bool exit = false;
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
    Console.WriteLine("Lookup ticket every {0} milliseconds", interval);
    Console.WriteLine("Cntrl-C to exit");
    Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cntrl-C Pressed");
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Dispose();
            exit = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    };
    DoWork();
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
    while (!exit)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  private static void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    DoWork();
  }
  private static void DoWork()
  {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Status response = client.status();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }
}
```

[image: x86 .NET 4.7][image: x86 .NET 6]